# How to extend the template binding syntax with custom properties accessible by children contexts?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, templating

I am trying to find an easy and elegant way to extend the template binding in order to propagate custom properties to children context. By extend, I mean to use the template binding with additional properties and not create another binding that will control descendant bindings (controlsDescendantBindings) because it requires another DOM element or KO virtual element.

This is what I would like to achieve:

```html
<div class="row"
     data-bind="template: {
         name: 'column-template',
         foreach: items1,
         properties: {columnType: 'col-md-6'}
     }"></div>
<div class="row"
     data-bind="template: {
         name: 'column-template',
         foreach: items2,
         properties: {columnType: 'col-md-12'}
     }"></div>
```

*or*

```html
<div class="row"
     data-bind="
         template: {name: 'column-template', foreach: items1},
         properties: {columnType: 'col-md-6'}
     "></div>
<div class="row"
     data-bind="
         template: { name: 'column-template', foreach: items2},
         properties: {columnType: 'col-md-12'
     }"></div>
```

...using whatever variation with:

```js
<script type="text/html" id="column-template">
    <div data-bind="css : columnType">...</div>
</script>
```

Note that the view model is shared by the 2 `<div class="row" />` elements, so I am not asking how to change the view model properties/observables. Instead, I would like to know if there is a mechanism to *extend* the native `template` binding **syntax** in order to make custom properties available in children contexts.

I have read some documentation or workarounds on extending contexts but could not find a solution which does not require extra HTML markup:

- http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html
- https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/354
- https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1002#issuecomment-19361275

For now, I am using a virtual binding handler suggested in a previous link:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.let = {
    init : function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // Make a modified binding context, with extra properties, and apply it to descendant elements
        var innerContext = bindingContext.extend(valueAccessor());
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(innerContext, element);

        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings['let'] = true;
```

...applied in this way:

```html
<!-- ko let: { displayMode: 'col-md-6' } -->
<div class="row" data-bind="template: { name: 'column-template', foreach: items1}}"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

*or*

```html
<!-- ko let: { displayMode: 'col-md-12' } -->
<div class="row" data-bind="template: { name: 'column-template', foreach: items2}}"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

It works as expected but looks a little verbose.

Thanks a lot!

This question has been asked originally here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knockoutjs/NvVIq72SeUY

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution if you use the following sintax:

```
<div class="row" data-bind="propertyTemplate: {
     name: 'column-template',
     foreach: items1,
     properties: { columnType: 'col-md-6' }
 }"></div>
```

The only difference with yours is that I renamed the binding to `propertyTemplate`.

Here's the binding code and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arielsvn/52E3Z/) to show it's working.

```
ko.bindingHandlers['propertyTemplate'] = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = valueAccessor(),
            context = bindingContext.extend(value.properties);

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { template: value }, context);

        return { 'controlsDescendantBindings': true };
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution but, as stated in my question, I am looking for a "mechanism to extend the native template binding syntax" and not how to wrap the native template binding in another custom binding handler.

Comment: What's the difference?? Isn't the result the same?? Why do you want to "extend the native template binding syntax" and wrapping around an existing binding doesn't work??

Comment: Probably because stackoverflow.com has become a place where members care about their reputation score instead of focusing on the question... ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late but I know it may help others so..

The basic idea is to keep the original binding handler and replace it with a new one while using the kept one to invoke the original functionality.

The main idea behind it:

```
var originalHandler = ko.bindingHandlers['handler'];
var customHandler = {
    extendBindingContext: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // extend here
        // bindingContext = bindingContext.extend(...);
        return bindingContext;
    },
    init: originalHandler.init
        ? function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            bindingContext = customHandler
                .extendBindingContext(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
            return originalHandler.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
        }
        : undefined,
    update: originalHandler.update
        ? function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            bindingContext = customHandler
                .extendBindingContext(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
            return originalHandler.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
        }
        : undefined
};
ko.bindingHandlers['handler'] = customHandler;
```

Hope this helps - And don't forget to up-vote please or even comment about success or issues - it's just some clicks away ;P